# Implementing Dagger 2 With RxJava and Retrofit 2 between Library modules of an App

Tags: android, rx-java, android-library, dagger-2, retrofit2

So, I have been working on an interesting project which is basically a mess of multiple library modules being consumed by an App Project.
These library modules are essentially self contained features except for 2 library modules which houses the 'common-codebase' and 'abstract-app' (sort of features as the name suggests).

My question is a fair one as I am new to Dagger 2; I would like to ask as to how to implement dagger 2 between a 'feature module' and the 'common-codebase' class. 
 Can anyone suggest me an alternate strategy for the same?
 Does anyone have any sample projects/gists/tuts I can have a look at?

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you have any samples? This questions seems far to broad and unspecific, especially since there should be no problem when using modules, just add dagger to your project and provide your classes